# After x groups of spaces select the next bunch of chars - regex

Tags: regex

I need help creating a reflex expression.

I have a file/string with a lot of lines, but I've only listed the first two as these are the only ones that matter. The value I am trying to extract is from the second line only and is the 5th group along; in this case it will the 2nd number 8. As you can see though, the first three bunches of chars are not words. The brackets are colour codes and need to stay there. There may also be another string further down like the second row, I need it to return the first value only (not multiple matches).

```
[56f442] M    WS  BS   S   T    W    A  Ld  Sv   [-]
[98ffa7]12"[-]   [98ffa7]3+[-]   [98ffa7]3+[-]   8   8   26   4   9   3+   [-][-]
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the “2nd line” the second line in the file? Do you want have the file as a single string where you’re using the regex?

Comment: well it's in a variable, so I guess it's one long string separated by line breaks. Yes, the whole thing should be treated as a single string

Comment: And what did your regex match? Please show it.

Comment: I don’t have one, I’m asking for help on writing it

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the group of non-whitespace `(\S+)` after the 4th group `(?:\S+\s+){4}` that's after the first newline `^.*?\n.*?`

```
^.*?\n.*?(?:\S+\s+){4}(\S+)
```

Comment: Would also happen to know how to search in the third line if I wanted? I tried adding an extra line with a new string and tested modifying the regex to \n\n (for two new lines) but this broke it :-(

Comment: I just figured it out. ^.*?\n.*?.*?\n(?:\S+\s+){4}(\S+) to go to three lines. thanks again sir!

Comment: Was thinking something like `^(?:.*?\n){2}.*?(?:\S+\s+){4}(\S+)`  But maybe you should find some method to process it line by line.